# Node.js Passport SAML from multiple Identity Providers

Tags: node.js, passport.js, saml-2.0

I've implemented [Passport-SAML](http://passportjs.org) into my site, and now I've been tasked with connecting our site with two other Identity Providers. In my code, it seems to use only the most recent definition of the SamlStrategy.  How can I set up Passport to allow multiple different implementations of the same Strategy?

My implementation looks like this:

```
passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
    {
        path: '/saml',
        entryPoint: "https://idp.identityprovider.net/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO",
        issuer: 'https://www.serviceprovider.com/saml',
        identifierFormat: 'urn:domain:safemls:nameid-format:loginid'
    },
    function(profile, done) {
        console.log("SamlStrategy done", profile)
        User.findOne({email:profile.Email}, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if(!user) return done(null, false, {message: 'No account associated with this email.'})
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can give each strategy a name

```
passport.use('config1', new SamlStrategy(..), callback);
passport.use('config2', new SamlStrategy(..), callback);
```

and then

```
app.post('/login/callback',
  function(req, res) {
      var config = // extract config name somehow
      passport.authenticate(config, { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true })();
  }
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
);
```

Comment: What if we store the configuration data in a database and users can set this up after the express server is started.  How can you instantiate new saml strategies in memory without restarting the express server?  I've seen this https://www.npmjs.com/package/passports but haven't really tried.  Just curious if you hit this problem

Comment: For setting up multiple SAML strategies on the fly, try [`MultiSamlStrategy`](https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml#configure-strategy-for-multiple-providers)

Comment: Thanks! This was super helpful for me as I was trying to create a saml proxy for azure AD (route multiple sso app logins) through a single node-js app

Comment: @woloski I would like to suggest edit as suggested by @dan , `MultiSamlStrategy`

Answer (score 1):

little fixes (and a lot of time saving :) ) to @woloski answer:

Giving strategy name:

```
passport.use( new SamlStrategy(name:'config1', ...), callback);
passport.use( new SamlStrategy(name:'config2', ...), callback);
```

and handling the post response:

```
app.post('/login/callback',
function(req, res, next) {
      var config = // extract config name somehow
      passport.authenticate(config, { failureRedirect: '/', failureFlash: true })(req, res, next);
  }
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
);
```

Cheers